# Why are my C# controls having IsDisposed set to true without Dispose method firing

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls

This is a head scratcher.  I have a form with a number of custom Controls on it.  The first time I create an instance of it everything works normally.

The problem occurs when I close the form and then create a second instance of it.  Some of my controls have an event that is (conditionally) raised during a mouse over.  In `OnMouseOver()` immediately prior to raising `MyEvent` everything is normal, but at the moment I enter the `MyControl_MyEvent` method `IsDisposed` is set to true on the form and all its child controls.  This happens despite the fact that breakpoints in the `Dispose` method of the form and controls are never triggered.

The course of events I described above isn't unique; I can trigger the same error in a few other places but haven't drilled through the call stack in quite as much detail trying to find exactly where `IsDisposed` gets set to true.

```
    //MyConrol
    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseMove(e);

        if (conditions)
        {
            if (MyEvent != null)
                MyEvent(this, new EventArgs());  //nothing disposed here
        }
    }

    //the first of several classes that have sbuscribed to the event
    void MyControl_MyEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //IsDisposed = true here if this is the second time the form has been displayed.
        DoStuff();  
    }


    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {   //the breakpoint here is never triggered
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

Can anyone suggest how I can figure out what is going on?

Comment: Can you paste the code where you destroy and recreate the form?

Comment: Like @cdhowie says, not enough info. I'd like to see a sample Dispose of those custom controls as well. Any static members?

Comment: @Henk Holterman See my comment on SLaks's answer, my EventHandler was static.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably forgot to unsubscribe from the events when the form is closed.

Therefore, when the second form is open, each event will be handled twice - once by the first form (which is disposed) and once by the second (which isn't).

As a debugging aid, you can right-click on `this` in the Locals window and click Make Object ID to see which instance is you're looking at.

Comment: A brand new form object should not have any attached event handlers from previous form instances...

Comment: @cdhowie: But the old form is (probably) still handling the events.  Obviously, this depends on what the event comes from.

Comment: @SLaks: Unlikely.  It looks like the events are being bound within the form (the handlers are private).  It's not a proof, but it's a best-guess scenario as we don't have a lot of code to go by.

Comment: This is probably the cause. If you look at the heap with a memory profiler you'll see two Forms, one of which is disposed but can't be collected because of the delegate(s) referencing them. The breakpoints are hitting in the disposed form.

Comment: Thanks for the debugging tip, I didn't know I could do that.  My EventHandler was static so that I could easily tie together almost a dozen controls (all sharing the same base class with the EventHandler declaration) so that the event being raised in any of them would call the event handler in all of them.

Comment: @Dan: You're welcome.  You should probably remove the handler in `Dispose` or `OnClosed`.

Comment: @SLaks  Yeah, fixing the problem shouldn't be hard now that I know what is actually causing it.

Comment: @SLaks  Do I need to worry about the designer messing with code I add into the `Dispose` method of classes derived from `Form` or `UserControl`?

Comment: @Dan: Just move the `Dispose` override from the Designer.cs to the main `.cs` file.  The designer will not put it back.  I've done this myself many times.

Comment: For completeness I also had related problems from non-static events belonging an instance of an object held by a static class.